# clearInterval in loop don't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, clearinterval

I have a problem
When I delete the letters, the word remains

I have two h1 I delete the word from each h1 and when all the letters are deleted I stop the interval for each h1 specially for it

[image: img]

```js
let mySelector = document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text");
for (let l = 0; l < mySelector.length; l++) {

  removeText = setInterval(function() {

    // Cut the last letter of the word and print the word after editing
    document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent =
      document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent.substr(0,
        document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent.length - 1);

    // Check if the entire word has been deleted
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent.length == 0) {
      clearInterval(removeText)
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="writ-text">gold</h1>
<h1 class="writ-text">golder</h1>
```

Comment: Use `const removeText =` instead. Currently `removeText` is being made a global variable, and so each iteration is overwriting the previous assignment. Adding `const` (or `let`)  keeps it scoped to the block of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cleared the only `setInterval` named `removeText`(global scoped) which makes it for both text.
Use a block scope like [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) to work out

```js
let mySelector = document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text");
for (let l = 0; l < mySelector.length; l++) {

 let removeText = setInterval(function() {

    // Cut the last letter of the word and print the word after editing
    document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent =
      document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent.substr(0,
        document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent.length - 1);

    // Check if the entire word has been deleted
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".writ-text")[l].textContent.length == 0) {
      clearInterval(removeText)
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="writ-text">gold</h1>
<h1 class="writ-text">golder</h1>
```

Comment: `this` in your callback refers to the `window` / global object (and not an interval id). This only works because the interval never gets cleared

Comment: Yes, you must use block scope variable as told by Nick Parsons, @user16733810

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: Try to read these article about: [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) & [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)